# Assigning memory to a pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

In a program I am developing I have this structure:

```
typedef struct _event {
  int id;
  char title[30];
  char desc[60];
  int state;
} event;
```

In a certain part of this program I will use a function who requieres a pointer to this struct.

```
void event_foo(event *e)
{
 /* Something will be done on this function, 
    with certain parameters of the pointer to the struct are needed */
}
```

But before accessing this function, I requiere to assign memory to this pointer to the struct.

```
int main()
{
  event newevent;

  /* In some place before invoking the function, 
     memory assignation is required */

  event_foo(&newevent);

  return 0;
}
```

¿Any suggestions to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you did is correct

the declaration you did

```
event newevent;
```

is allocating static memory for `newevent` with type `event`

and when you called the function

```
event_foo(&newevent);
```

adding `&` at the beginning of `newevent` that means that you have provided the address (pointer) of  `newevent`  as input argument for the function

Into the function you can modify the parameters of the structure

**Example**

```
void event_foo(event *e)
{
  e->id = 5;
  strcpy(e->title, "any string");
  strcpy(e->desc, "any string2");
  e->state = 1;
}
```

And in the `main()` and after calling the `event_foo()`, you can access to your data in this way

```
event_foo(&newevent);
printf("id = %d\ntitle = %s\ndesc = %s\nstate = %d\n",
       newevent.id,
       newevent.title,
       newevent.desc,
       newevent.state);
return 0;
```

Comment: @CristianC. so what you are looking to do ? this way to allocate memory for the struct and treate it is correct.

Comment: Maybe you're right in your answer, because the type of memory needed isn't specified.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
event newevent;
```

creates a stack allocated instance of `event`, with memory already provided for it. This memory will be valid until `newevent` goes out of scope. If `event_foo()` is going to read any members of `newevent` and not just update them then you must initialize the members of `newevent` before calling `event_foo()`.

If you had declared a pointer to `event`:

```
event* newevent;
```

then it would be necessary to allocate memory for `newevent` before accessing its members:

```
newevent = malloc(sizeof(*newevent));
```

in this case the memory for `newevent` exists until `free(newevent)` is called.

Comment: In this case in particular, the memory allocation is needed to be done before invoking `event_foo()`, and the idea is doing it without modifying the arguments of the same function. Is there any change in the parameters of `event_foo()` if I declare the pointer to event? (the second case you named).

Comment: None, but when invoking don't use address of operator.

Answer (score 0):

if e is needed only to point to the object passed as argument then there is no need to assign memory to it.through pointer we are directly accessing the objects memory location so we can do any changes directly to the members of the passed object